# MySQL command line client for Linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I just installed MySQL 5.6 in a new CentOS 7 Linux installation.  I want to use the MySQL command line client that I have been used to using in Windows, but I cannot seem to find it.  Is there a MySQL command line client for Linux?  If so, how do I make sure that I have it?  And how do I open it up in the GUI?

Comment: `mysql` is the MySQL client in command line. There is no GUI apart from the terminal window.

Comment: just issue: mysql -u mysq_user -p in the terminal. This will let you enter the mysql command line.

Comment: @unixmiah Only assuming they have a mysql server running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open MySql command line utility using following command

```
mysql -u user_name -p
```

It will ask for password for user_name. If password is not set call as follows

```
mysql -u user_name
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the service is running :

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Then make sure to run the security script that will remove some dangerous defaults and lock down access to our database system a little bit.

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Now you can use the [command line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html)

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```